# Open a single Pages document in two windows?

Tags: pages

In Pages is it possible to open a single document in two windows?

Example:

I have a 10 page document called "Recipes."
I want to see pages 3 & 8 of the "Recipes" document on screen at the same time.  I can then scroll from page 3 to 4 and onwards, while page 8 remains on screen.

There are lot of work arounds (such as open the document in Word or Preview). But I would like to be able to do it all in Pages.

Hopefully, there is some terminal command or something that I have missed.

(I know I can send Feedback to Apple, but who knows how long before they create such a feature).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _open a single document in two windows_?

Comment: @Monomeeth I have added an example.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty clear to me that the ask is for two views into **the same** document, either two windows, or a split screen — as has been offered in Word and many other word processors and text editors for a long time.

I believe the short answer is no.

See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1972415?start=0&tstart=0